# JSON Object and Simple Type to Model in WebAPI using FromBody

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating a Web Api method that should accept a JSON Object and a Simple Type. But all parameters are always `null`.

My json looks like

```
{
"oldCredentials" : {
    "UserName" : "user",
    "PasswordHash" : "myCHqkiIAnybMPLzz3pg+GLQ8kM=",
    "Nonce" : "/SeVX599/KjPX/J+JvX3/xE/44g=",
    "Language" : null,
    "SaveCredentials" : false
},
"newPassword" : "asdf"}
```

And my Code looks like:

```
[HttpPut("UpdatePassword")]
[Route("WebServices/UsersService.svc/rest/users/user")]
public void UpdatePassword([FromBody]LoginData oldCredentials, [FromBody]string newPassword)
{
  NonceService.ValidateNonce(oldCredentials.Nonce);

  var users = UserStore.Load();
  var theUser = GetUser(oldCredentials.UserName, users);

  if (!UserStore.AuthenticateUser(oldCredentials, theUser))
  {
    FailIncorrectPassword();
  }

  var iv = Encoder.GetRandomNumber(16);
  theUser.EncryptedPassword = Encoder.Encrypt(newPassword, iv);
  theUser.InitializationVektor = iv;

  UserStore.Save(users);
}
```

Comment: Yep, i use postman to test my api.

Comment: Please check my bellow answer and let me know whether its working or not

Comment: @Kingpin, clarify if using asp.net-web-api or asp.net-core

Comment: I am creating an ASP.NET Core Web Application with the Web API Template. Because it is just a rest service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current JSON you are sending maps to the following classes

```
public class LoginData {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string Nonce { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public bool SaveCredentials { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateModel {
    public LoginData oldCredentials { get; set; }
    public string newPassword { get; set; }
}
```

[FromBody] can only be used once in action parameters

```
[HttpPut("WebServices/UsersService.svc/rest/users/user")]
public void UpdatePassword([FromBody]UpdateModel model) {
    LoginData oldCredentials = model.oldCredentials;
    string newPassword = model.newPassword;
    NonceService.ValidateNonce(oldCredentials.Nonce);

    var users = UserStore.Load();
    var theUser = GetUser(oldCredentials.UserName, users);

    if (!UserStore.AuthenticateUser(oldCredentials, theUser)) {
        FailIncorrectPassword();
    }

    var iv = Encoder.GetRandomNumber(16);
    theUser.EncryptedPassword = Encoder.Encrypt(newPassword, iv);
    theUser.InitializationVektor = iv;

    UserStore.Save(users);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, creating a help-class combing both was the solution. I was used to wcf where it is possible to have more than one paramter.

Comment: It is possible. but the way you are sending the data and trying to access in the parameters don't match up. that is why they were always null.

Answer (score 2):

More than one **[FromBody]** does not work in Api. Check this [Microsoft Official blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

So now you can do like this, create a `complex object` which should contain both your oldCredentials and newPassword. For example *LoginData* class in my example bellow. And *myLoginRequest* is another object class which is to `deserialized` your *LoginData*.

```
[HttpPut("UpdatePassword")]
[Route("WebServices/UsersService.svc/rest/users/user")]
public void UpdatePassword([FromBody]LoginData MyCredentials)
{
 loginRequest request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myLoginRequest>
                            (json.ToString());

 // then you can do the rest
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api), "At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body". Means only one parameter can contain [FromBody]. So in this case it will not work. Create one complex object and add required properties to it. You can add newPassword to your complex object to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class DocumentController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult PostDocument([FromBody] Container data)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data.Document)) return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "No document attached"));

            return ResponseMessage(IndexDocument(data, Request));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, ex.Message));
        }
    }

}



public class InsuranceContainer
{
    [JsonProperty("token")]
    public string Token { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("document")]
    public string Document { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}




var fileAsBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\tmp62.pdf");
String asBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(fileAsBytes);


var newModel = new InsuranceContainer
    {
       Document = asBase64String,
       Text = "Test document",
    };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newModel);

using (var stringContent = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://www.mysite.dk/WebService/api/Document/PostDocument", stringContent);
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        var message = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(message.Result);


    }
```